# prevent scroll after page reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I save current scroll position using the following way:

```
$(window).on('unload', function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() != 0) {
        localStorage.setItem('lastScrollPosition', $(window).scrollTop());
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
    }

});
```

After page reloading I load images and I need to scroll at `lastScrollPosition` only when all images are loaded. So I call `$(window).scrollTop(lastScrollPosition)` after all images are loaded, browser scrolls at `lastScrollPosition`, but after that browser also scrolls at top of page (like `$(window).scrollTop(0);`), therefore, I get these action: $(window).scrollTop(lastScrollPosition) -> $(window).scrollTop(0)

Could you please advise how to fix my issue?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle to better explain the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason of the issue. This way works correctly, but a instagram library scrolls to top after my scroll. So this library has strange behavior.